# Transaction out of gas but gas used less than gas limit

Tags: contract-development, gas, out-of-gas, gas-limit, rinkeby

I have this method on a contract that I'm testing on rinkeby

```
function addMatch(string _name, uint _fixtureId, uint8 _home, uint8 away, uint _start) public onlyOwner returns (uint8) {
    require(_home < NUM_TEAMS && _away < NUM_TEAMS && _home != _away);
    require(_start >= now);
    Match memory newMatch = Match({
        home: _home,
        away: _away, 
        fixtureId: uint2str(_fixtureId),
        winner: 0, 
        start: _start, 
        name: _name
    });
    uint8 matchId = uint8(matches.push(newMatch));
    string memory url = strConcat(
        "json(https://api.basketball-matches.org/[my api key]/", 
        newMatch.fixtureId,
        ").[?(@.status=='FINISHED')].result[scoreHome,scoreAway]");
    bytes32 oraclizeId = oraclize_query(_start + QUERY_INTERVAL, "URL", url);
    oraclizeIds[oraclizeId] = matchId;
    emit MatchCreated(matchId);
    return matchId;
}
```

No matter how much I set the gas limit to the transaction still fails, however the gasUsed displayed on ether scan is less than the gasLimit (which I set to the limit of the network). 
Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be. I'm using web3 and using infura through the truffle HDWallet provide.

[image]

Attempting to estimate the gas cost using web3 just throws an error. The error returned when I call this method on the blockchain is:

```
Error: Transaction ran out of gas. Please provide more gas:
```

Comment: Could be that one of your require-clauses interrupt the transaction

Comment: @gisdev_p seems it was, forgot about timezones, but why throw an out of gas error, does require consume all remaining gas? Also, mind making your comment an answer so I can give you the rep

Comment: It should not consume all gas, and I don't think that it does . At least in the screenshot of your question the gas used is different and much smaller than the max gas

Comment: Odd error to return in such a case then, but thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the parameters of your function call, it looks like one of your require-clauses interrupt the transaction.